# A question about triangle centers

Tags: geometry

I need to check some triangle centers using their Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ but I'm not sure how to go from this notation, for example, as seen on this website:

http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html

to explicit formulae which would give me the result in terms of coordinates.

Eg. if I wanted to calculate the centroid of $$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$$

I know I would get it simply by $$ \left(\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3} , \frac{y_1 + y_2 + y_3}{3}\right)$$

So I was just wondering is there a straightforward way to go to this kind of representation for all those centers on the website?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates#Conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates#Conversions), the conversion from trilinear to cartesian coordinates is as follows:

$$ \alpha : \beta : \gamma \mapsto
\frac{a\alpha}{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}\begin{pmatrix}x_A\\y_A\end{pmatrix} +
\frac{b\beta}{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}\begin{pmatrix}x_B\\y_B\end{pmatrix} +
\frac{c\gamma}{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}\begin{pmatrix}x_C\\y_C\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here $\alpha:\beta:\gamma$ denote the trilinear coordinates. These greek letters are therefore not angles but describe a proportion of distances to the triangle edges. $a,b,c$ are the lengths of these edges. $x_A$ through $y_C$ are the 2D Cartesian coordinates of the three corners. Edge $a$ is the one opposite corner $A$ and so on.

Written in a less vectorized fashion:

$$
x = \frac{a\alpha x_A + b\beta x_B + c\gamma x_C}{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma} \qquad
y = \frac{a\alpha y_A + b\beta y_B + c\gamma y_C}{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}
$$

In the case of the centroid, you have $\alpha=\frac1a, \beta=\frac1b, \gamma=\frac1c$ so you can see that the stated formula gives the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have known it was only one wikipedia article away! :)

But your answer clarifies it nevertheless!